# Word for a person who quotes well?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word to describe a person who makes up nice quotations?

Comment: A person who *makes up* nice quotations is a liar.

Comment: _Quotable,_ perhaps?

Comment: The term "quotable" is probably the most idiomatic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Someone who makes something up isn't quoting anything, but they might coin a particularly quotable phrase.

Such a phrase can be called an **epigram**,

> a pithy saying or remark expressing an idea in a clever and amusing way
>
> [[ODO]](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/epigram)

...and the person who concocts it is called an **epigrammatist**.

Comment: Churchill used to roll his own. Here's one: 'It is a good thing for an uneducated man to read books of quotations.'

Answer (score 3):

Depending on usage, perhaps you should coin a new word that fits with what you are writing.  Sometimes the best usage of words is to create new words that others will understand even if they aren't part of the common vernacular.

The person is a quotemaster.

They are very quotiferous.

They are double plus quotable. (I love and hate Newspeak)

Comment: Maybe 'quotehound' along the lines of 'rockhound'?